# How do I get Android to dynamically refresh a url

Tags: android, rest, service, refresh

I have used the Udacity Google Developing Android Apps tutorial and other sources to get my application to fetch an XML file in HTTP via an AsyncTask and display it via a ListAdapter.

Now I am trying to eliminate the refresh button and have it update when the app starts, and then at intervals afterwards.

As far as I can tell, even though the code at Udacity creates a Service, it doesn't eliminate the refresh button.

The code at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#exercise_bindlocalservice only refreshes when the list is clicked.

Does anyone have sample code where the list auto refreshes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my questions were answered by using the BasicSyncAdapter example from Google.

Answer (score 0):

yourListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
or you can use activity life cycle to update the activity through onResume() or onStart() if needed! but i guess you are looking for the first answer to refresh ur listAdapter

Comment: I guess I am looking for a resource that will give me an explicit answer. The Google tutorial doesn't seem to eliminate having a refresh button, I would like to eliminate it.

From the Linux command line, this is just:

`watch "curl -s \"http://demo:demo@demo.opennms.org/opennms/rest/outages?limit=10&query=ifRegainedService%20is%20null&orderBy=ifLostService\"|perl -ne 'print \"\$1\n\n\" if /<logMessage>([^<]*)/'"`

Answer (score 0):

if your `auto` means the content will update whenever there are new contents. You should check those new content by yourself , the classical way is set a `Timer` to check it . After you got the new content , you can use them to update the view .

Update:

See this:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

The reason for not using Timer is not because `Timer` does 'bad things' but Android does, All running task or data will be stopped and recycled by Android's GC at anytime , so the `Timer` will be terminated at anytime.

> If you have a service or an activity in your application which should perform a repetitive task you cannot reply on a TimerTask or similar approaches and control it from your Android component. Activities and services can be terminated at any point in time by the Android system to free up resources.

So , you can rely on `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` in the tutorials I post above.

Comment: That's exactly what Vogella says **not** to do. [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)